# Pesquisa binário mips

Tags: assembly, mips

Estou desenvolvendo um código em mips com o objetivo de realizar uma busca binaria recursivamente, bem ao longo do desenvolvimento surgiram algumas dúvidas, sendo elas:

1. Logo após minha chamada de função, eu desempilho meus argumentos, mas também devo desempilhar meu $ra? Realizando como abaixo:

   ```
   lw $s0, 0($sp)  # desempilha o valor a ser buscado
   lw $s1, 0($sp)  # desempilha valor Ult
   lw $s2, 0($sp)  # desempilha valor Pri
   lw $s3, 0($sp)  # desempilha ref vetor A
   lw $ra, 0($sp)  # desempilha o $ra
   ```
2. E ao final quando vou realizar a chamada recursiva eu preciso antes empilhar todos os meus argumentos também certo? Além do meu $ra? A propósito, é ele que ira controlar para que eu não me perca nas chamadas da recursão?

Se alguém puder, gostaria de um exemplo simples.

Observação: Sei que a passagem de argumentos não deve ser feita utilizando pilhas com convenção do mips, mas esse trabalho exige esse procedimento.